# SQL Server 2005 i want to create the hour a task was started out of an datetime

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime, datepart

On SQL Server 2005 i want to create a representation of the hour that my task was started. I have a datetime that is '2010-10-01 12:30:00.000' which is the actual start time. What i would like to end up with is '12:00' which is the hour the task was started. Any good ideas on how to loose the '30' minutes?

Comment: Do you want `12:00` (as a string), or `2010-10-01T12:00:00` (still as a datetime value)?

Comment: I need to keep it as a datetime value so that i can use it in a 'between' clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @dt datetime 
set @dt = '2010-10-01 12:30:00.000'
select convert(char(5), dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, @dt), 0), 108)
```

Result:

```
12:00
```

As a datetime

```
declare @dt datetime 
set @dt = '2010-10-01 12:30:00.000'
select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, @dt), 0)
```

Result:

```
2010-10-01 12:00:00.000
```

Comment: this is exactly what i need (as datetime). Anyway i can get the time only and keep it as datetime?

Comment: @Peter - a datetime will always have a date part. If you need to compare times of different date you could modify the values to have the same date part before comparing.

Comment: I changed the input to a string value before comparing and it is working perfectly thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to eliminate minutes/seconds/mills from a datetime value, but keep it as a datetime, use `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF`:

```
select DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,`2010-10-01T12:30:00`),0)
```

Which will return `2010-10-01T12:00:00`.

Comment: The only datetime related datetype in SQL Server *before* 2008 is `datetime`. This always has both a date and a time component, even if you don't specify them in, say, a string literal used to initialise it. If you just want to compare the hour portions of two datetimes, ignoring both dates, and ignoring minutes, just use `DATEPART(hour,<value>)` and compare integers.

Comment: Hi Damien, i followed you and Mikael's advice and just changed the input date so that i could compare the time(hour) only. Thank you so much for your help on this. Everything is working great

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, '20000101', [DateField]), '20000101')
```